# JAVA - Xsd:dateTime conversion

Tags: java, soap, xsd, wsdl

I have a big problem with which I've been fighting for several hours ...
So my scenario is:
I have a webService in soap developed in java under websphere6.1 and java 1.5
my problem is the dates with xsd Datetime
my backend returns as Calendar Date 2017-10-31T00: 00: 00Z but when it comes back from the service with a client either SoapUI, Rad WS tester, that a client developed in java, this date returns to me with a different value, ie 2017-10-30T23: 00: 00Z ..

Comment: you mean to say it's one hour difference from the client??

Comment: the server have 2017-10-31T00:00:00Z and the client show 2017-10-30T23:00:00Z

Comment: please check the timezone, i faced the same issue as server was placed in different timezone

Comment: the timezone is the same, i have it in local, and i have UTC timezone (Z)

Comment: that even you can see in your computer date-time settings wizard.

Comment: i have utc on my computer

Comment: that's not your code issue, it's timezone issue, i guess your local system and the server system timezone differs. please check your Date-Time wizard, there it will be specified

Answer (score 0):

Issue with timezone settings not the DateTime conversion. Please check your server timezone

Comment: I do not think .. because the service backend converts a string from the yyyyMMdd format to the calendar type in the correct way..but the client receives it wrong